# Binding to custom buttons

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, custom-controls

I have a self-made button that has image and text.

```
<ButtonImageApp:ButtonImage   
BText="Button"
```

This works fine. But when I try to to do binding my button code is broken.

This wont work.

```
BText="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.PlayButton, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

XAML

```
<Button x:Class="ButtonImageApp.ButtonImage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        IsEnabledChanged="ButtonIsEnabledChanged"
        MouseEnter="ButtonMouseEnter"
        MouseLeave="ButtonMouseLeave">

    <Grid>
        <Image Stretch="None"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
           x:Name="image" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtButtonText"  
            Foreground="Black"             
            Text="{Binding Path=BText}"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
            Margin="20,51,0,-51" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

The Code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonText = DependencyProperty.Register("BText", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonImage), null);
public string BText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonText); }

    set
    {
        SetValue(ButtonText, value);
        txtButtonText.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `LocalizedStrings` and `LocalizedResources`? Post the code for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when using binding the setter of the property is not called. 
Instead you need to register for the dependency property changed:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonText = DependencyProperty.Register("BText", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonImage), new PropertyMetadata(ButtonTextChanged));

    private static void ButtonTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtButtonText.Text = e.NewValue;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, Got it working:
((ButtonImage)d).txtButtonText.Text = (string) e.NewValue;